# Discord.py bot - Send message to discord server if statement is true

Tags: python, discord

I want to send a message to my discord server whenever my if statement is true. The problem i run into is that it looks like Discord requires some sort of event to fire off before being able to send a message to the server. I can't find any way to do this.

```
def checkCoinSell(coin):

mfiValue = getMfiValue(coin)
vwapValue = getVwapValue(coin)
currentPrice = float(getCurrentCoinPrice(coin))

if currentPrice > vwapValue and mfiValue >= 75.0:
    
    coinsToSell.remove(coin)
    coinsToCheck.append(coin)
    #Send message in a channel on my Discord server
```

Answer (score 0):

```
channel = client.get_channel(channelId)
await channel.send('your message')
```

This code should do it. Make sure that channelId is an integer